# Inserting dash into string via 'sed'

Tags: sed, insert, character, line, digits

I have 14-character line containing digits. How do I insert a char into it at the specific location, i.e. at 4th?

So, if I have string like this

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

how do I change it to something like this

```
xxxx-xx-xxxxxxxx
```

and whereby x is for a digit?

Thanks!
irek

Answer (score 8):

If your lines *only* contain your digits, you can group the first four characters in a group:

```
\(....\)
```

and the following two ones in another group:

```
\(....\)\(..\)
```

Then, you just replace it by a backreference to the first group (`\1`), a dash, a backreference to the second group (`\2`) and another dash:

```
\1-\2-
```

The result:

```
$ echo 12345678900000 | sed 's/\(....\)\(..\)/\1-\2-/'
1234-56-78900000
```

Comment: This was as simple as breathing through nostrils.. thanks a ton..

Answer (score 3):

Thanks brandizzi for your answer it helped me to get my one to work using a slightly different method

```
sed 's/^\(.\{4\}\)\(.\{2\}\)/\1-\2-/'
```

the 4 and 2 work to replace the 4th character and then 2nd after that with dashes.

So xxxxxxxx becomes xxxx-xx-xx