# Date format change in csv

Tags: python, linux, csv

I have a csv file containing dates in a specific format and want to change to yyyy-mm-dd format. The column of csv looks like this

```
date-submission
20230805090756
20230906080856
```

and i want all date in date-submission column to look like

```
2023-08-05
2023-08-06
```

all dates should look like this any help with linux bash or python would be helpful

Comment: What have you tried?  You can do this with a simple `sed` script.

Comment: I tried few bt nothing is working  @TimRoberts

Comment: It is expected that you provide your code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are OK with `awk` here is one sample script to do the work:

```
awk 'NR!=1{printf "%s-%s-%s\n", substr($1,1,4),substr($1,5,2),substr($1,7,2)}'  input_file >tmp_file
mv tmp_file input_file
```

To make it inplace the command must be something like:

```
gawk -i inplace 'NR!=1{printf "%s-%s-%s\n", substr($1,1,4),substr($1,5,2),substr($1,7,2)} NR==1 {print}'  input_file
```

Comment: How to update my file with this command @Romeo Ninov

Comment: IT's working bt how to get the file updated with this command

Comment: @sysadmincrispy, you can redirect the output of `awk` to temporary file and then move this temporary file to your source file.

Comment: @sysadmincrispy, I update the answer this above idea

Comment: is it possible to directly apply changes to the same file

Comment: @sysadmincrispy, not in `awk`. `sed` can do it, but I have no so much experience with this utility

Comment: thanks bt this not the only column i have many columns so if this was happening inline it would done the trick just manupilating single column

Comment: @sysadmincrispy, add extract from real file, with all columns so we can tune the script(s) to work with your data

Comment: there is a gawk inplace option to pass file but i am  not getting the syntax correctly

Comment: Tried but throwing posix or gnu style options some issue i think

Comment: @sysadmincrispy, work for me, even on busybox

Comment: which version of gawk

Comment: @sysadmincrispy, GNU Awk 5.1.1

Comment: I am looking for possibilities to change the output of the command with sed

Comment: @sysadmincrispy, "_I am looking for possibilities to change the output of the command with `sed`_", it is recommended to provide such information within your initial question and description. Whatever, [`sed` inserting dash into string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914974/) will answer that.